# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Shell' for ipython

Tags: python, django, shell, virtualenv

I have installed ipython on my machine inside virtual environment like below

```
pip install ipython

Downloading/unpacking ipython
  Downloading ipython-2.0.0.tar.gz (11.9MB): 11.9MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ipython

Installing collected packages: ipython
  Running setup.py install for ipython
    checking package data

    Installing ipengine2 script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing iptest script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing ipython2 script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing ipcluster2 script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing ipcluster script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing ipython script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing ipcontroller2 script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing ipcontroller script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing iptest2 script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing ipengine script to /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin
Successfully installed ipython
Cleaning up...
```

So when i start my shell from inside virtualenv as `python manage.py shell` i am seeing below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 29, in handle_noargs
    shell = IPython.Shell.IPShell(argv=[])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Shell'
```

Django version - 1.2.3
ipython version inside venv - 2.0.0

So why it is appearing and how to avoid, i din't experienced this previously

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by upgrading Django to 1.2.7.

```
pip install --upgrade django==1.2.7
```

If that's not possible, you could try installing an old version of IPython, but I haven't tested if that works.